# A derivation problem about the Lewis-Riesenfeld theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, time-evolution

I am read the [original paper](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/10/8/10.1063/1.1664991). There is one step I cannot understand. Namely, the highlight sentence below.

How to understand $i \frac{\partial }{\partial t}$ as a Hermitian operator? How to prove that the diagonalization is always possible?

Attached is the first part of their paper.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How much QM and linear algebra do you know? It is a fundamental result that a Hermitian operator is diagonalizable. Their way of putting it is rather strange, though, since the time derivative isn't an operator.

Comment: I have been doing QM for 10 years. But, I cannot make sense of their statement.

Answer (score 0):

±H is hermitian already, so all we need is to see why $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is also Hermitian.

By definition this requires
$$
\langle \phi | i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} | \phi \rangle^*
$$
But since
$$
 \langle \psi | i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} | \phi \rangle^* =  \langle - i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi  | \psi \rangle
$$
this means
$$
\langle \phi | i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}  \rangle = \langle - i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi  | \psi \rangle
$$
and further
$$
i\hbar \left[ \langle \phi | \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}  \rangle + \langle \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}   | \psi \rangle \right] = 0 
$$
$$
i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle \phi(t) | \psi(t) \rangle = 0\;\;\; \forall\;\phi(t),\;\psi(t)
$$
That is, $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is Hermitian as long as the evolution is unitary, which it is.